# How Long Does Salesforce Keep Apex Job Logs?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

Does Salesforce delete Apex Job history after some interval of time (e.g. 1 week)? Or is it displayed in my org indefinitely?

Answer (score 12):

From [Monitoring the Apex Job Queue](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_apex_job.htm&type=5):

> All batch jobs that have completed execution are removed from the batch queue list seven days after completion.

(It's the last sentence).